# In C# convert numbers to bytes without allocation

Tags: c#, arrays, math, garbage-collection

How can I convert a numerical value (e.g. `float`, `short`, `int`, ...) to several `byte` values without having to allocate memory on the heap for an array, like `System.BitConverter.GetBytes` does?

Something like this:

```
public static void GetBytes(short input, out byte byte0, out byte byte1)
{
    //demo code, just to show which results I need
    var bytes = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(input);
    byte0 = bytes[0];
    byte1 = bytes[1];
}
```

Note: I'm restricted to .NET Framework 4.8 and therefore (I think) C# 7.3.

Comment: Why would that ever be a problem ?

Comment: @Franck The allocation is a problem in tight loops of a few milliseconds; not always upfront, but it'll cost the Garbage Collection further down the road

Comment: You allowed to use `unsafe` code?

Comment: Reading every byte out of it on the fly will unbox and make hundred fold more instruction on CPU and that you think would be faster than a single allocation ?

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes

Comment: @Franck: how/where does (un)boxing come into play here?

Comment: @mike you will be casting every byte as you go

Comment: @Franck but casting is not the same as (un)boxing, or? boxing would indeed allocate mess on the heap.

Answer (score 6):

Just cast and shift?

```
public static void GetBytes(short input, out byte byte0, out byte byte1)
{
    byte0 = (byte)input;
    byte1 = (byte)(input >> 8);
}
```

Note that you can simply reverse the order for different endianness.

Note that if you are using a "checked" context, you would need to mask too:

```
public static void GetBytes(short input, out byte byte0, out byte byte1)
{
    byte0 = (byte)(input & 0xFF);
    byte1 = (byte)((input >> 8) & 0xFF);
}
```

(in an unchecked context, the cast to `byte` is sufficient by itself - additional bits are discarded)

Comment: Sorry for asking, but: what do you mean by "checked"?

Comment: @mike See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/checked-and-unchecked).

Answer (score 2):

If you are allowed to use unsafe code, then for non-integral value types (such as `float`, `double` and `decimal`) the fastest way is to use a pointer.

For example, for a `double`:

```
double x = 123.456;

unsafe
{
    byte* p = (byte*) &x;

    // Doubles have 8 bytes.

    byte b0 = *p++;
    byte b1 = *p++;
    byte b2 = *p++;
    byte b3 = *p++;
    byte b4 = *p++;
    byte b5 = *p++;
    byte b6 = *p++;
    byte b7 = *p;
}
```

You should be able see how to modify this for other types.

For integral types such as `short`, `int` and `long` you could use the approach given in the other answer from Mark Gravell - but you can also use the pointer approach above for integral types.

IMPORTANT: When using the pointer approach, endianness is significant! The order in which the bytes are assigned is the order in which they are stored in memory, which can differ by processor architecture.

Comment: how does microsoft's implementation of `BitConverter.GetBytes` (decompiled: `public static unsafe byte[] GetBytes(short value){ byte[] bytes = new byte[2]; fixed (byte* numPtr = bytes) *(short*) numPtr = value; return bytes; }`) deal with different processor architectures?

Comment: BitConverter doesn't deal with the endiannes. "The order of bytes in the array returned by the GetBytes method depends on whether the computer architecture is little-endian or big-endian." See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.getbytes?view=net-6.0#system-bitconverter-getbytes(system-double)

Answer (score 0):

To emphasize on [Mark Gravel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73786244/14860947)

I have implemented a simple method, to demonstrate an example.

```cs
public static void CopyWithoutAllocation(long value, Span<byte> dest)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < sizeof(long); i++)
    {
        dest[i] = (byte)((value >> 8 * i) & 0xFF);
    }
}
```

this can be modified to be generic and support other numeric types.

Answer (score -1):

You can put here any ValueType.

```
public static Span<byte> AsSpan<T>(ref T val) where T : unmanaged
{
    Span<T> valSpan = MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref val, 1);
    return MemoryMarshal.Cast<T, byte>(valSpan);
}
```

Then you can do it in reverse.

```
public static T Convert<T>(ref Span<byte> span) where T : unmanaged
{
    return MemoryMarshal.Read<T>(span);
}
```

Usage:

```
    int i = 123;
    float f = 0.000_1f;
        
    Span<byte> spanInt = AsSpan(ref i);
    Span<byte> spanFloat =AsSpan (ref f);

    int i2 = Convert<int>(ref spanInt);
    float f2 = Convert<float>(ref spanFloat);
        
    Console.Write($"{i2} {f2}");
```

Comment: How does that correspond to the OP's "I'm restricted to .NET Framework 4.8"?

Comment: You're right. It cannot be used with 4.8( My bad. Downvote if you'd like.